# Python: How to remove quotes around numbers from string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a python string like this:

```
"""
{id: 'id_0_4', value: '8450223051', name: 'XAD3', parent: 'id_0'},
{id: 'id_0_5', value: '509071269', name: 'ABSD', parent: 'id_0'}
"""
```

From the string, I want to remove the single quotes around the numbers that appear after `value`.

How can I write a regex that will detect only such numbers and replace the quotes around them?

Comment: have you tried using `int`?

Comment: It's a shame this isn't legal JSON, which would make it much cleaner to just parse, fix up, and serialize back.

Comment: how would i make it legal JSON. i tried json.dumps but that does not have any effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capture the number in a group, re-insert the group:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """{id: 'id_0_4', value: '8450223051', name: 'XAD3', parent: 'id_0'}, {id: 'id_0_5', value: '509071269', name: 'ABSD', parent: 'id_0'}"""
>>> re.sub("'(\d+)'", r'\1', s)
"{id: 'id_0_4', value: 8450223051, name: 'XAD3', parent: 'id_0'}, {id: 'id_0_5', value: 509071269, name: 'ABSD', parent: 'id_0'}"
```

Or, if this must be specific to the number after 'value':

```
>>> re.sub("(value:\s*)'(\d+)'", r'\1\2', s)
"{id: 'id_0_4', value: 8450223051, name: 'XAD3', parent: 'id_0'}, {id: 'id_0_5', value: 509071269, name: 'ABSD', parent: 'id_0'}"
```

Comment: @AbtPst note while this technically answers your question, I'd much rather use a string that you could `ast.literal_eval` or load with the `json` module and then change the value(s) of the resulting dict in a more robust way. So maybe fix your string format upstream.