# How to remove ' ' around numbers after concatenating pd df/ python3 jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, jupyter-notebook

I have two dfs in python3, jupyter.  After I merged them, there are '' around all the numbers, I would like to know how to remove them. thx!

I tried different ways to concatenate...

```
new2['mer']=new2[['imgId_f','label','.jpg']].astype(str).apply(lambda r: "".join(r), axis=1)

new2['mer']=new2[['imgId_f','label']].astype(str).sum(axis=1) 

new2['mer']=new2['imageId']+new2['labelId'].map(str)+new2['.jpg']
```

but didn't make any differences, all of them have '' around the numbers.

the df looks like this:

```
    id   label                   imgId_f        .jpg    mer
0   1   [95, 66, 137, 70, 20]   id_1_labels_    .jpg    id_1_labels_['95', '66', '137', '70', '20'].jpg
```

the '95' in "id_1_labels_['95', '66', '137', '70', '20'].jpg" is where i have problem with

Comment: @DyZ thank you, i just edit it, took the screenshot off and add a simple df to show the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316120/python-how-to-remove-quotes-around-numbers-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem values in column `label` are lists of numbers.

Possible solution is convert numbers to `string`s and merge together by [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
new2['mer'] = new2['imageId'] + 
              new2['label'].map(lambda x: [str(i) for i in x]).str.join(',') + 
              new2['.jpg']
print (new2)
   id                  label       imageId  .jpg  \
0   1  [95, 66, 137, 70, 20]  id_1_labels_  .jpg   

                               mer  
0  id_1_labels_95,66,137,70,20.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

after @DyZ 's sharing link, I figured I wasn't searching with a proper keyword. I found this solution too:

```
new2['mer'] = new2['mer'].apply(lambda s:s.replace("'", ''))
```